# Codeigniter - Active Record - Query - Metódo de atualização Banco de Dados

Tags: php, codeigniter

Olá!
Faço esta pergunta a fim de tirar uma dúvida que tenho, e de poder ler idéias de outras pessoas, de como posso inserir ou excluir um item, a um determinado `operador_id`.

Como mostra a primeira imagem, ao carregar um formulário de cadastro de `operadores`, eu listo todas as `unidades` cadastradas no sistema.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Então eu seleciono `uma` ou `mais` unidade, cujo `operador` deverá pertencer.

E ao clicar em salvar, o `objeto operador`, que está marcado de vermelho será enviado conforme imagem a seguir:

Onde o que está selecionado de verde, é(são) a(s) unidade(s), cujo o `operador` percente.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Vejam a estrutura do banco de dados, na imagem a seguir.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A minha dúvida começa aqui.
Se for para inclusão, eu consigo utilizar o método, como no exemplo abaixo:

```
public function incluir_unidade($dados, $operador_id)
{
    $array = (array) $dados;
    foreach ($dados as $uni)
    {
        $unidade = [
            'ope_id'        => $operador_id,
            'uni_id'        => $uni->unidade_id,
        ];
        $this->db->insert($this->tb_operador_unidade, $unidade);
    }
}
```

Mas eu queria entender, como posso fazer no caso de atualização:
Para inserir, excluir `unidade(s)` ao `operador`.

Levando em consideração os quadros abaixo:

- `Unidade A` existe no array, porém já existe no banco (neste caso não faz nada)
- `Unidade A` existe no array e não existe no banco de (neste caso, inclui)
- `Unidade A` não existe no array, mas existe no banco (neste caso, deleta do banco de dados)
- `Unidade A` não existe no array e não existe no banco (neste caso, não faz nada).

Este exemplo é só o que imagino, se houver outra forma de se fazer, eu gostaria de saber..

Comment: Wagner, em caso de atualização, eu excluo todos os itens pertencentes a este usuário, e recadastro, com base na array enviada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode chamar um método `verificar_unidade()`, por exemplo, antes de executar o `incluir_unidade()` e nesse método você faz um `SELECT` trazendo todas as unidades cadastradas para o determinado operador. Dessa forma você pode comparar o que está sendo inserido com o que já está inserido na tabela.

Também pode ter um método `remover_unidade()` que será responsável por remover as unidades que não serão mais associadas ao operador.

*Model*:

```
public function verificar_unidade($operador_id)
{
    $this->db->select('unidade_id');
    $this->db->from('tb_operador_unidade');
    $this->db->where('operador_id', $operador_id);

    return $this->db->get();
}

public function remover_unidade($unidade_id, $operador_id)
{
    $this->db->where('unidade_id', $unidade_id);
    $this->db->where('operador_id', $operador_id);
    $this->db->delete('tb_operador_unidade');
}
```

*Controller* (dentro do seu método que salva os dados):

```
// Array com os IDs das unidades que estão sendo inseridas. Ex.: 1, 4 e 6
// Não entendi exatamente como está recebendo esses valores via POST, por isso deixei estático.
// Isso deve ser dinâmico e deve ser ajustado no seu código.
$unidades = [1, 4, 6];

$consulta = $this->nome_do_seu_model->verificar_unidade($operador_id);

if ($consulta->num_rows())
{
    // Se encontrou registros, o operador já possui unidades. Vamos verificar:

    foreach ($consulta->result() as $unidade)
    {
        if ( ! in_array($unidade->unidade_id, $unidades))
        {
            // Remove unidades que estão na tabela, mas não estão no array.
            $this->model->remover_unidade($unidade->unidade_id, $operador_id);
        }
        else
        {
            // Estão na tabela e no array, então remove do array p/ evitar INSERTs duplicados
            $chave = array_search($unidade->unidade_id, $unidades);

            unset($unidades[$chave]);
        }
    }

    // Aqui itera o array $unidades p/ realizar INSERTs 
    foreach ($unidades as $unidade)
    {
        // O ID da unidade deve ser passado como parâmetro junto com ID do operador
        // Aqui chama o método: $this->nome_do_seu_model->incluir_unidade();
    }
}
else
{
    // Não possui unidades, faz só os INSERTs...
    // Aqui chama o método: $this->nome_do_seu_model->incluir_unidade();
}
```

Comment: @WagnerFilho Você tentou fazer da maneira como postei aqui?

Comment: Seu *array* deve ser igual o `$unidades` e não dessa forma como comentou. É ele quem vai controlar as inserções e remoções. Por isso que comentei no código que você deve adequar no seu *script*.

Comment: Mas é isso o que o código está fazendo. `$unidades` armazena os IDs das unidades que estão sendo cadastradas e em seguida a consulta traz os IDs cadastrados pra fazer a comparação. Se houver unidades na tabela e não no *array*, chama o método de exclusão, senão vai tratar o *array* pra gerar os `INSERTs`.

Comment: O método `result()` vai trazer os dados em forma de objeto. Tanto que são acessados via `$unidade->unidade_id`, por exemplo. Você pode trazer em *array* também, mas vai ter que readequar o código.

Comment: eu coloquei como resposta, como ficou após algumas alterações, mas aceitei a tua resposta. a recompensa, darei assim que der o prazo..

Comment: me ajuda com isso: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/274978/compara%C3%A7%C3%A3o-entre-array-e-banco-de-dados-inclus%C3%A3o-e-exclus%C3%A3o-codeigniter

Answer (score 0):

Fazendo algumas alterações sobre a resposta do Paulo, segue como ficou e funcionou...

Foi alterado o método `result` para `result_array` e retirado um `foreach desnecessário`.
 Também foi alterado os parâmetros de consulta..

```
$verifica_unidade = $this->operador->verificar_unidade($operador_id);

    if ($verifica_unidade->num_rows())
    {
        // se encontrou registros, o operador já possui unidades. vamos verificar:
        foreach ($verifica_unidade->result_array() as $unidade)
        {               
            if (!in_array($unidade, $unidades))
            {                   
                $this->operador->remover_unidade($unidade['uni_id'], $operador_id);             
            }
            else
            {
                // estão na tabela e no array, então remove do array p/ evitar INSERTs duplicados
                $chave = array_search($unidade, $unidades);
                unset($unidades[$chave]);
            }
        }               
            $this->operador->incluir_unidade($unidades, $operador_id);
    }
    else
    {
        // não possui unidades, faz somente os INSERTs...
        $this->operador->incluir_unidade($unidades, $operador_id);
    }
```