# Comparação entre Array e Banco de dados, Inclusão e exclusão Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Eu resolvi nesta [questão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/273824/codeigniter-active-record-query-met%C3%B3do-de-atualiza%C3%A7%C3%A3o-banco-de-dados/273923?noredirect=1#comment561090_273923), uma dúvida que tive sobre incluir e remover items que estava no array e não estava no banco de dados ou vice-versa.

Então tentei usar o mesmo método para um cadastro de equipe, mas não funcionou.
Alterei algumas linhas, mas sem sucesso.

***Vejamos:***

No `objto_equipe` existe um atributo chamado `equipe_operador` do tipo `array`,

No atributo `equipe_operador` será enviado `equipe_id e operador_id`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A questão agora, fica por conta do método que irá gerenciar a inclusão e exclusão do banco de dados.

A regra geral do cadastro de um operador na equipe é:

- O `operador_id` NÃO pode ser associado a mais de uma equipe_id, portanto, se no array o `operador_id` é igual a 1 e no banco de dados este `operador_id` for igual, porem a equipe for diferente, então apaga o que está no banco de dados e inclui o que está vindo no array.
- Sempre que vier no array `equipe_id = 0`, significa que o operador não faz parte de nenhuma equipe

Ate o momento cheguei na seguinte método.

***Model***

```
public function verificar_equipe($operador_id)
{
    $this->db->select('operador_id, equipe_id');
    $this->db->from($this->tb_operador_equipe);
    $this->db->where('operador_id', $operador_id);
    $query = $this->db->get();

    return $query;
}
```

```
public function incluir_equipe($dados, $equipe_id)
{
    $array = (array) $dados;
    foreach ($dados as $equ)
    {
        $id = $equ->operador_id.$equipe_id; // concatena equipe_id + operador_id
        $equipe = [
            'id'          => $id,
            'equipe_id'   => $equipe_id,
            'operador_id' => $equ->operador_id,
        ];
        $this->db->insert($this->tb_operador_equipe, $equipe);
    }
}
```

```
public function remover_equipe($equipe_id, $operador_id)
{
    $this->db->where('operador_id', $operador_id);
    $this->db->where('equipe_id', $equipe_id);
    $this->db->delete($this->tb_operador_equipe);
}
```

***Controller***

```
    foreach ($equipes as $_equipe => $obj_equipe)
    {
        $verifica_equipe = $this->equipe->verificar_equipe($obj_equipe->operador_id);           
        //print_r($obj_equipe);
        if ($verifica_equipe->num_rows())
        {
            // se encontrou registros, o operador está associado a uma equipe. vamos verificar:
            foreach ($verifica_equipe->result() as $equipe)
            {
                // está na tabela e não está no array, então remove da tabela
                if (!in_array($equipe->operador_id, $equipes))
                {
                    print_r($equipe->equipe_id);                        
                    $this->equipe->remover_equipe($equipe->equipe_id, $equipe->operador_id);
                }
                else
                {
                    // estão na tabela e no array, então remove do array p/ evitar INSERTs duplicados
                    $chave = array_search($equipe, $equipes);
                    unset($equipes[$chave]);
                }
            }               

            $this->equipe->incluir_equipe($equipes, $equipe_id);
        }
        else
        {
            // não possui equipe, faz somente os INSERTs...
            if ($obj_equipe->equipe_id == 0)
            {
                print_r("Inclusão de IDs que não existe no banco");
                //$this->equipe->incluir_equipe($equipes, $equipe_id);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: fiquei confuso quando começou a explicar a regra.

Comment: a regra é que no banco de dados só pode ter um único operador_id.

as tabela do banco é `id, operador_id e equipe_id`, se no banco já existir um `operador_id = 1 e equipe_id = 1`, mas no array, está vindo `operador_id = 1 e equipe_id = 2`, então no banco de dados, deverá ficar conforme o array.